# Laravel - Nested if

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to check if user already logged in and user is female I show specific image otherwise show another image. Here is my code:

```
@if(Auth::check())

    <a id = "login-popup-title" href="profile" >
      profile

        @if ( {{Auth::User()->gender}}  == "w" )
            <img src="assets/img/profile-f.png">
        @else
            <img src="assets/img/profile-m.png">
        @endif
    </a>
@else
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal">register / login
        <img src="assets/img/lock.png">
    </a>
@endif
```

In our table, we save user's gender information as `w` (woman) and `m` (man).

But I get an error:

> FatalErrorException in 33957561dccca78dc8674528d604ac88fdbdaef8.php line 74:
>       syntax error, unexpected '<'

How to do that?

Comment: You should not use Blade delimiters inside `@if` conditions, so `@if ( {{Auth::User()->gender}}  == "w" )` should be this `@if (Auth::user()->gender  == "w")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
@if ( {{Auth::User()->gender}}  == "w" )
```

Since you're already in an `if` block, you don't need the curly braces - those are only for printing. Do this instead:

```
@if ( Auth::User()->gender  == "w" )
```

As it stands, Laravel will convert it to something like this:

```
<?php if <?php echo Auth::user()->gender; ?> == "w": ?>
```

And I'm sure you can see why that wouldn't work. :) That's why it's complaining about an unexpected `<`.